# Adding a unit toggle to MS Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2003

**TL;DR**

I'm trying to perform some calculations on the values entered to a data entry form before saving them into a table.

---

**Background**

I have a form in MS Access that serves as a front end for entering data into our database.  It is mostly distance data between a datum and various objects.  The database and the applications that use that data have all been set up expecting all the measurements in feet, but a lot of our sources for the data are in meters.  In the past, the user had to convert the data on their own before inputting it into the form.  This extra step slows down productivity, and increases the chance of user error.

What I want to do is add a radial button to my form that lets the user swap between meters and feet.  When it is swapped to meters, all the values for that record are converted to their meter equivalent before being displayed on the screen.  If the user changes a record or creates a new one, the form will need to convert the values back into feet before updating the table.  It's very important that the values in the table always remain in feet.

I was able to find [this article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-access/conditional-record-source-for-a-form/752c0164-8035-48fa-82a4-844ce5ac4b3d?auth=1) that describes how to swap between record sources for a form.  I think I can just set up 2 queries - one that pulls the data directly from the table, and one that performs the conversion - and swap between the queries as my record source when the user toggles the radial button.

---

**The Problem**

The issue with this set up is that since I have to use aliases in my queries to perform the conversion, the user cannot enter data while the radial is toggled to meters.  If I try to update one of those fields, I just get a bing noise and the input is ignored.  **Is there any way to allow inputs when the radial is toggled to meters?**  As I said above, it is important that the data in the table is always in feet, so if the user has the 'meters' option selected and inputs a value like `500`, the value entered into the table should be `1640`, which is the result from the conversion to feet.

---

**Sample**

Here's simplified example of what my queries look like

FEET query

```
SELECT A,B,C AS LEN,D,E
FROM TABLE1
```

METERS query

```
SELECT A,B,C/0.3048 AS LEN,D,E
FROM TABLE1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query only:

```
SELECT A,B,C AS LEN,D,E
FROM TABLE1
```

On your form, hide the textbox bound to LEN.

Create a new unbound textbox, say, txtLEN.

Now use code like this where SelectMetric is the checkbox to mark when using metric values:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Dim Factor As Currency

    If Me!SelectMetric.Value = True Then
        Factor = 0.3048
    Else
        Factor = 1
    End If        
    Me!txtLen.Value = Factor * Me!LEN.Value

End Sub

Private Sub txtLen_AfterUpdate()

    Dim Factor As Currency

    If Me!SelectMetric.Value = True Then
        Factor = 0.3048
    Else
        Factor = 1
    End If        
    Me!Len.Value = Me!txtLEN.Value / Factor

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had tried something like this (with 1 query and a hidden textbox), but instead of putting the conversion in the code, I tried to just do it in the control source for txtLen, and I got the same results as I had with the 2 queries.  I tried it your way and moved it into the code, and it looks like it's working perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: One thing to note: looks like I need to have a `Me.Requery` in the `AfterUpdate` event for my radial button as well so that the screen is refreshed right after the user swaps between units.

Comment: Yes, forgot that, sorry. You could also just call `Form_Current` - that should be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

Just change what is displayed in the textbox. Set up the text box to have a control source of

```
=Length*txtConversionFactor
```

Where `txtConversionFactor` is a hidden textbox which either has `1` in it if your units are to be displayed in feet or 0.3048 if they are to be displayed in meters. It could even be a combobox bound to a table like this

```
MultiplyFeetByToGetOutputUnits    OutputUnits
1                                 ft
0.3048                            m
12                                in
0.000189394                       mile
```

Then you can convert to whatever you want without changing your form.

Comment: @Gustav well I'm not editing this because your answer does basically what I'd do except I'd table drive.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but yeah, this is similar to one of the things I tried, and as Gustav pointed out, it still doesn't allow you to edit values.